# java JAR file works in Windows but not Linux (centos-7.6)

Tags: linux, java

I have a *STIGViewer-2.8.jar* file.  This works fine in Microsoft Windows 7 or 10, but does not work in Centos-7.6 linux.  In linux when doing `java STIGViewer-2.8.jar` I get

```
Error.  Could not find or load main class StigViewer-2.8.jar
```

I have `jdk-8u191-linux-x64.rpm` installed, and this is Centos *Server with GUI* so I am in runlevel 5 with full graphics, everything else is working... Libreoffice, freecad, unameit.   Is there some trick I need to do to get jar files to run in linux?  Or is it a java thing and a problem with the jar file being *Windows only*?

Comment: `java <classname>` or `java -jar <filename>`.

Comment: using `java -jar StigViewer-2.8.jar` produces the same error: **could not find or load main class**.

Comment: I would also like to know why it works in Windows I can double click on a .jar file and it works, but in linux it does not; when double-clicking on .jar file from the windows explorer thing in linux I cannot use the folder/explorer thing it doesn't run via java instead it opens it like a container file.

Comment: @ron Can you are confirm using Oracles and not the openjdk .RPM?

Comment: I downloaded `jdk-8u191-linux-x64.rpm` from oracle and did a `yum install` on it.  Then this jar file did not work.  So using software gui i installed openjk 1.6, 1.7, 1.11; 1.8 already installed.

Comment: currently `/usr/bin/java -version` shows **openjdk version 1.8.0_201-b09**

Comment: Thanks. I've encountered this before but it has been awhile since I used STIGviewer. The jar file is not OS specific, historically it has worked anywhere the appropriate Java version is installed: usually Windows and Linux, but I believe it will work on OS X and others, so long as you have an appropriate GUI and Java. Let me do a bit more digging...I *know* I've overcome this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like add that Red Hat has documented this issue for RHEL 7: [DISA STIG viewer does not run with OpenJDK](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3520331). This link needs a Red Hat login to work, so I will reproduce the key information here.

> Environment: Red Hat Entreprise Linux 7 (RHEL7), OpenJDK 1.8
>
> Issue: DISA STIGViewer does not run with OpenJDK:
>
> ```
> $ java -jar ./STIGViewer-2.7.1.jar
> Error: Could not find or load main class stigviewer.STIGViewer
> ```
>
> Resolution: Use Oracle's JRE instead of OpenJDK for that application. Oracle's JRE or JDK has to be downloaded from Oracle's website.
>
> Root Cause:  OpenJDK cannot be used because the DISA STIGViewer application uses JavaFX internally which is not provided by OpenJDK.

Note that the default Java 8 binaries on RHEL 7/CentOS 7 come from the `java-1.8.0-openjdk` package.

The [STIG Viewer 2.x User Guide](http://iasecontent.disa.mil/stigs/pdf/STIG_Viewer_2.x_User_Guide_June_2018.pdf) also mentions this under Section 1.1 Notes:

> This tool is produced in Java, and delivered as a single JAR file. It
>   requires the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) be installed on the user’s
>   machine to run (**i.e., to run the STIG Viewer tool, Oracle Java is
>   required**). This allows the program to be run on any operating system
>   for which the JRE is produced. This also limits the program to running
>   at the permission level of the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 3):

Having EPEL respository active, using software gui I **removed** all the **OpenJava** or **OpenJDK** stuff; did a search on *java* and unchecked using good judgement.  Some things like *json-glib* or *python-javapackages* or *tzdata-java* I left alone.

then i did a `yum install jdk-8u191-linux-x64.rpm` which is from oracle.

That shows up in software gui as `jdk1.8-2000:1.8.0.201-fcs` with no *Open* wording, and all the *OpenJava* or *OpenJDK* stuff is not installed.

After that it **works** only using **java -jar StigViewer.jar**

If I do just *java StigViewer.jar* I still get the error, and if I double click on the .jar file from the windows explorer it opens the file like it was a container.

When installing centos 7.6; I chose *Server with GUI* and I think there was a choice for java stuff but if there was I know I didn't choose, so it seems centos installs openjava automatically to some extent.

**update:**

**oracle** jdk-8u201-linux-x64.rpm results in `/usr/bin/java` **link** to `/etc/alternatives/java` which then points to `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201-amd64/jre/bin/java`

it is THIS oracle java that works with this *stigviewer.jar* file only by `java -jar stigviewer.jar`

Other software like *Octave* and *plplot* rely on *OpenJDK Headless Runtime Environment 8* which is `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1:1.8.0.201` and that results in the `/usr/bin/java` still linking to `/etc/alternatives/java` and that links to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java` which is no workie for this *stigviewer.jar* file.

So I can remember to manually run Oracle's `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201-amd64/jre/bin/java` when I need to.  It seems once OpenJDK is at all installed, the oracle rpm will not overwrite the links.

Comment: Your issues are also compounded by the $PATH and which `java` executable was being called. I downloaded and installed the jdk1.8-1.8.0_201 .RPM from Oracle; then I changed the /etc/alternatives link to point to /usr/java/latest/bin/java; finally, I executed `/usr/java/latest/bin/java -jar ./path-to/STIGViewer-2.8.jar` and successfully opened the app.
Glad you worked it out!

Comment: If you are using a JAR file you must use the `-jar` parameter before the name of the JAR file.  That is in the `man` page for java and also mentioned in `java -help` command.